# Android phonegap childbrowser: Flashvideo still plays sound after closing childbrowser

Tags: android, audio, video, cordova, flash

In my app, one of my childbrowser links points to a site with a flash video, shown with flowplayer. After closing the childbrowser, the sound of the video still plays for about 7-15 seconds. Any ideas to stop the sound immediately?

snippet from my phonegap index.html head:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                var childBrowser;
                function onBodyLoad()
                {
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
                }
                /* PhoneGap has been initialized and is ready to roll */
                function onDeviceReady()
                {
                    phoneGapReady.innerHTML = "PhoneGap is Ready";
                    childBrowser = ChildBrowser.install();
                }
                function openChildBrowser(url)
                {
                    try {
                        //both of these should work...
                        window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url); 
                        //childBrowser.showWebPage(url);
                    }
                    catch (err)
                    {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                }
                function closeChildBrowser()
                {
                window.plugins.childBrowser.close(); 

                }

                </script>
```

and later in the body:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openChildBrowser('http://192.168.1.200/4/2/flowplayer/example/index.html');">click here for video</a>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: damn, I solved it for myself, I just editet the childbrowser.java:   
private void closeDialog() {
        if (dialog != null) {
         this.webview.loadUrl("http://www.some-stupid-blank-page.xxx");
            //this.webview.stopLoading();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

Comment: Hey, can you test it with sending it to about:blank? If that works for you I will make the change to the code on github.